# Pass props to a child component on page load - react with next.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and Next.js. I'm trying to pass down props to a child component from a fetch request to my backend (express server / MySQL database. The returned data is in json format and is currently being printed to my browser window. The child component is a ProductList, which contains the rendered Products.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

import ProductList from '../components/ProductList/ProductList';

const Index = () => (

    <div>
        <ProductList products={products}/>
    </div>

)
Index.getInitialProps = async function () {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000');
    const data = await res.json();
    return {products : data}
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: Did you get the right solution for it? I am also looking for the right solution for exact question you have mentioned..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan The problem I had was I was sending my request to the same endpoint on my server, as the endpoint for the page I wanted next js to SSR render. See this other post about it that I made, where we managed to get it solved: [link(]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002970/initially-fetch-data-and-pass-props-to-another-component) . Apologies for duplicate posts, I didn't realise this was still up. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: To solve it, just change the fetch request to an endpoint that is different to the pages. I.e. "http://localhost:3000/give-me-a-random-initial-endpoint-to-fetch

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will take a look into this..

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 ways to do it. One solution is for client-side (react) and the second one is for server-side (nextjs).

**Client side - React**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ProductList from '../components/ProductList/ProductList';

const Index = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState()
    
    // This logic is only executed when the component is mounted
    useEffect({
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000');
        const data = await res.json();
        setProducts(data)
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <ProductList products={products}/>
        </div>

    )

export default Index;
```

**Server side - NextJS**

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import ProductList from '../components/ProductList/ProductList';

const Index = ({products}) => (
    <div>
        <ProductList products={products}/>
    </div>

)
Index.getInitialProps = async function () {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000');
    const data = await res.json();
    return {products : data}
}

export default Index;
```

When a value is returned from `getInitialProps`, it is injected as a prop into the page component, the page component then receives those values as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a state for the products and fill it from `useEffect`. As the `useEffect` should only run on the first render, we pass it an empty array of dependencies. Also, remember to handle any error from the fetch.

```
const Index = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProducts = async () => {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000");
            const data = await res.json();

            setProducts(data);
        };

        getProducts();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <ProductList products={products} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Cheers Alvaro! This works great. Is there a way to do it using Next.js's getInitialProps method?

Comment: @DominicLane you are welcome. Sorry I overlooked your use of `getInitialProps`. The solution I'm proposing is just a standard React way. If you need to use `getInitialProps` I can't help you as I have no experience with it. If that's the case lets see if someone can be of more help.

Comment: No problem - cheers for taking a look. Usage of getInitialProps is used in Next.js as the pages are server-side rendered. The above works great if you're routing to "LocalHost:3000", but not if you're initially loading it.