# Initially fetch data and pass props to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce, next.js

I have honestly (and perhaps ashamedly) been flummoxed by this for well over a week now. I've read the Next.js documentation back to front and have scoured the web for hours. I am clearly missing something and would appreciate it if someone could take a look.

When Index.js gets loaded, it sends a request to my database (via) express and this returns a json response. The intention is for my ProductList component to .map() this response - which has been passed to it via props - into my individual products.

With the below code, I can get my index.js to render the products when I initially load another page and then link to it client side. However, I can't get Index.js to load my products if I initially load this page.

[Json views][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c6hf.png

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import NavBar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

import '../styles/styles.css';

import ProductList from '../components/ProductList/ProductList';

const Index = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <ProductList products={props.products} />

        </div>
    );
};

Index.getInitialProps = async () => {

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/');
    const data = await res.json()
    return {products: data}

}

export default Index;
```

ProductList.js

```
import ProductTile from '../ProductTile/ProductTile';

class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "md:flex">

            {
                this.props.products.map(product => {
                    return (
                    <Link href={`/product?product_ID=${product.product_ID}`}>
                    <a><ProductTile product = {product} key={product.product_ID}/></a>
                    </Link>
                )})

            }

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ProductList;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

require('dotenv').config()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const pool = require('../lib/db');

//routers
const productsRouter = require('./routes/products');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()
  server.use(cors());
  server.use(morgan('dev'));
  server.use(bodyParser.json());

  server.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM products', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      //console.log(results);
      res.send(results);
    });
  })

/* Routers for product router and user router here

*/

  server.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (!err.status) {
      err.status = 500;
    }
    res.status(err.status).send(err.message);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Comment: Is there no errors in the console? What does logging `data` in `getInitialProps` log? Are you correctly looking at the logs in your terminal (as it's server-rendered)?

Comment: Did you install React Dev Tools browser extension so you can inspect props given to your components ?

Comment: Hey @yachaka , thanks for your reply. 1. I get the following error: "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.", if I SSR an auxiliary page ("/cart") and then go back to to home ("/"). However, because nothing is rendered if I go directly to the home ("/"), I don't get this error.

Comment: @yachaka Yes, I have React Dev Tools and the props are passing correctly (as far as I can see) and I have the different keys.

Comment: The warning about children keys is because you put the `key` attribute on the `<ProductTile />` component but you should be putting it on the `<Link />` component (the outer-most)

Comment: If you inspect the HTML source code, after SSR-rendering the index `/`, what do you see? Where does the rendering end?

Comment: My pleasure ----

Comment: Re "Keys": brilliant, thanks. Re "HTML": interesting. The Next.js modules are not called at all. If "/" is client-side rendered, all the next modules are called. Thus, there is no HTML at all. It seems Firefox and Chrome are just rendering the raw JSON because next hasn't provided the framework? This must be an issue server side right?

Comment: That's interesting yeah, do you use a custom express.js server?

Comment: Correct. I have added my "server'js" file to my post. Maybe that might leave a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Based on your `server.js`, I'd say it comes from this.
In which folder is `index.js`? To which route it responds to ? Eventually, it could be in your routers code.

Do you see the request coming in, logged, in your server? Can you log it inside your `index.js` server route?

Comment: Index.js is in the pages folder. I think you've invoked a rationalisation. Might it be because my fetch request is at the same endpoint as my root page. Thus, when the initial page is loaded, before next.js sends the modules client-side, it sees the get request to the database and that json response "beats" the modules clientside?

Comment: ahah, it was. I changed my getinitialprops request to "localhost:3000/initialproducts" and my get request server side to the corresponding endpoint. Thanks so much mate! I have been stuck on this for a week!

Comment: Ahah nice it's often something easy like this